# HTML/CSS(/JS?) for Responsive 2 Element Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, responsive-design

I'm looking to create a horizontally scrolling slider, where two elements are visible within the viewport at any given time.  The viewport is a container div whose width is controlled by media queries, so it's fully responsive.  If the viewport gets small enough (mobile), I'd like the 2 visible elements to stack.  Here's a visual of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX19v.png

The biggest issue I'm running into is because I want to show 2 element as once.  The container div is responsive, but the ul inside of it is much wider.  So I can't set the width of the elements to 50%, because it will be 50% of the whole ul.

Can I accomplish the styling for this with just CSS, or will I have to use some javascript to manage the width of these things too?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try Twitter Bootstrap, it has a specific responsive CSS layout that will do this kind of thing for you. I don't use it create entire sites, but it's features are pretty good, check it out:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

No, please don't use JavaScripts to handle that. You can use [Twitter Bootstrap's fluidGridSystem](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) to support a responsive style. You also can share code at http://jsfiddle.net/ so that people can help you more easily.